# HERE Map Attributes API 8: Potential Missing Layers

Tags: here-api, here-fleet-telematics

I am trying to use the newer HERE Map Attributes API v8 to access various layers and while some work (e.g. SPEED_LIMITS_FC1...5) others do not (e.g. TRAFFIC_SIGN_FC1..5) and return a 400 responseCode: *Layer XXX has no LAT / LON columns*

What little documentation there is for HERE Map Attributes API 8 ([link](https://developer.here.com/documentation/content-map-attributes/dev_guide/topics/here-map-content.html)) lists these layers as available (however it seems that the documentation is just copy/pasted from the older Fleet Telematics API and hasn't been updated)

Note: I am able to access these layers using the older HERE Fleet Telematics API.

Is anyone able to shed insight on what might be occurring? Are these layers still accessible in HERE Map Attributes API v8 or is my API request just incorrect?

Is there additional documentation/examples for HERE Map Attributes API v8 that isn't just copied from HERE Fleet Telematics API?

Comment: It appears that my problem is that the TRAFFIC_SIGN_FC1..5 can only be accessed through tiles (in=tile:) and not via a corridor (in=corridor:) like other attributes such as SPEED_LIMITS_FC1...5. Hope that helps for anyone encountering the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

All the layers are accessible. The request parameters are a bit different. Please refer to the [API documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/content-map-attributes/api-reference.html).

You can try the below sample to retrieve the data from the layer of SPEED_LIMITS_FC1...5. Please replace the place holder of {apiKey}with the real one.

```
https://smap.hereapi.com/v8/maps/attributes?in=tile:430628&layers=SPEED_LIMITS_FC1&apikey={apiKey}
```

The tileId 430628 is computed based on the following logic, which is documented in the section "Tiles & Tile Sizes (Levels)" of [the online guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/content-map-attributes/dev_guide/topics/here-map-content.html).

```
  tile size = 180° / 2^level [degree]
  tileY = trunc((latitude  +  90°) / tile size)
  tileX = trunc((longitude + 180°) / tile size)
  tileID = tileY * 2 * (2^level) + tileX
```